# update the database with a python script and csv file

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a sample csv file

```
number    name        age
 1       John K,      40
 2       Jordan       35
 3       Kristen      25
 4       Prime        33
```

I also have a sample table in `mysql`

```
id     number      age
 1       1         
 2       3
 3       4
 4       2
```

How do I update the table using python with my csv file?

desired  result

```
id    number     age
1       1        40
2       3        25
3       4        33
4       2        35
```

I'm thinking to update the table using

```
query = update table1 set age = {} where number = {}
```

How do I iterate through my csv and update the table accordingly using python?

Comment: break the task into 2 parts. 1) Load a csv file and iterate over the rows. 2) For every row execute SQL Update. Share the code so the community can help

Answer (score 0):

I would always be careful with testing your script on a live sql database. If you make a mistake you will overwrite your information unless you have a backup.

You could consider these two options.

1. Load your data from the csv and db into a separate df and left join both frames  and push the result to sql.
2. Make an additional sql table with the age variable and join the tables inside sql.

If you still want to try your solution you can loop through your csv using pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['John K,','Jordan','Kristen','Prima'],
          'age' : [40,35,25,33]})

for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    print(rows.age)
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```py
db = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}: 
{1}@{2}/{3}'.format(database_username, database_password, database_ip, 
database_name))
conn = db.connect()

data= pd.read_csv('youFileName.csv', engine='python')

for index, row in data.iterrows():
     age= row['age']
     number= row['number']
     args = (age, number)
     conn.execute(UPDATE_QUERY, args)

conn.close()
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66611603/2) to the question [update the database with a python script and csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66611603/update-the-database-with-a-python-script-and-csv-file) by the OP [astroboy1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15211816/astroboy1) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>